# My SQL database isn't working, getting #1064 error

Tags: mysql, php

When I attempt to upload this database to my server I get the following error.
I'm not sure what's wrong with my code, please help me.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `<?php`

```
// Create connection
//$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $p' at line 1
```

[image: Picture of Code]

Comment: This question doesn't have much to do about "database-design", but just about programming + specifics MySQL. Tags should be changed. You should also remove your screenshot and paste the source code instead, so that people who might give you an answer can copy it and simulate its behaviour. You should also point out, if at all possible, *which* is the statement (line number, stack trace, or any other debugging information) that is generating the error.

Comment: Are you trying to run a PHP script using `mysql`?

Comment: Run the SQL on the MySQL client app first - see what happens then. Preferably use the native cli tool rather than a GUI which can introduce other issues.

Comment: Apparently you are trying to send PHP code to MySQL directly. MySQL can only run SQL, not PHP

Comment: One last tip: there're like a hundred programming editors out there. There's no need to make your eyes bleed with the only one that doesn't have absolutely any basic feature, not even syntax highlighting.